# ID3 binary tree or non-binary tree?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I'm trying to implement ID3 or C4.5 algorithm.

According to ID3 algorithm, the information gain is calculated as follows:

[image]

For example: training data like this:

```
credit      age      label   
normal     young      yes
normal     old      yes
bad        old        no
excellent  middle     yes
```

The IG of credit should like this: `IG(credit) = H(D) - P(credit==normal)H(D|credit==normal) - P(credit==bad)H(D|credit==bad) - P(credit==excellent)H(D|credit==excellent)`

When I choose the credit as the best feature to split, in the following procedure, I will not consider the attribute "credit" again.

However: I also see some one implemented like this:
`IG(credit=normal) = H(D) - P(credit==normal)H(D|credit==normal) - P(credit ~= normal)H(D|credit ~= normal)`

When I choose credit == normal as the best feature to split, in the following procedure, I will consider the attribute "credit" again, like credit == "bad".

The resulting tree of different IG calculation procudure, one is non-binary tree, the other is the binary tree.

My question is whether two trees are equivalent? When I do testing on two trees, the results will always be the same? Or one is better than other? Or hard to say which is better, just depends on the data?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned, one tree will perform multiway split the other binary split. The 2 trees are definitely NOT equivalent, hence the test results will also not be the same.But the accuracy in both cases could be in a similar range. To suggest you on the last 2 questions regarding which model is better depends on your data.